# how to add multiple grids in SAGA gis

Tags: import, saga, mosaic

Here is the "big" problem: my Digital elevation model is divided in a lot of pieces (single files .xyz).

In order to build a mosaic of them I need to import them all. With SAGA I can import them just one by one (Import grid from xyz). Is there an option or an easier way to import them all together?

P.S.: I'm using SAGA 2.1.2

Comment: you could try scripting saga from the commandline..convert all to saga grids, then script a "merge or mosaic" call to create one raster.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options deppending on your .xyz datasets:

1) .xyz datasets are in grid structure - the easy way

Since GDAL supports .xyz files - http://www.gdal.org/frmt_xyz.html you can use the:

`GDAL/OGR -> GDAL: Import Raster` module.

That module supports multifiles selection so it'll do the job. The target cellsize is automaticaly derived from gridded data.

2) .xyz datasets are not precisely grids (rows <> columns)

You should use batch with saga_cmd interpreter. This batch will look something like that (code assumes all .xyz's are stored in one directory, same where the bat is).

```
FOR %%G IN (*.xyz) DO saga_cmd io_grid 6 -GRID %%~nG.sgrd -FILENAME %%G
```

As a result you'll see SAGA's .sgrd files in working directory - then you can drag and drop all .sgrd's to SAGA GUI.

If you need you can add another flags to saga_cmd line:

> Usage: saga_cmd [-GRID ] [-COUNT ] [-FILENAME ]
>   [-CAPTION] [-CELLSIZE ] [-SEPARATOR ]
>   -GRID:  Grid 
>    Data Object (optional output)
>   -COUNT:          Count
>           Data Object (optional output)
>   -FILENAME:       File Name
>           File path
>   -CAPTION              Has Field Names
>           Boolean
>           Default: 1
>   -CELLSIZE:       Target Cellsize
>           Floating point
>           Minimum: 0.000000
>           Default: 1.000000
>   -SEPARATOR:      Separator
>           Choice
>           Available Choices:
>           [0] space
>           [1] tabulator
>           [2] ,
>           [3] ;
>           Default: 1

If you're more familiar with batch you can merge/mosaic all tranformed gridds in same script (as @user1269942 commented).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot find the right module: with GDAL/OGR Import Raster I don't have all the options as there are in your link.  I just have "Select multiple Bands" and "Transformation". The result is an empty map. The module gdal_grid isn't also in the list of the modules in the software folder... where can I find or download it?

Comment: I've updated my answer. This link describes what type of xyz gdal supports. Please try options i descriped in answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another solution:
1) place all the files of the digital elevation model in the same folder
2) open the MS-DOS command line and enter in the folder (cd ...) 
3) digit: "copy *.xyz name_file.xyz"

In the end you'll get a single file (name_file.xyz) of all the other (with the end .xyz) together.